# How to add a column in an already existing table and fill IDs in it ordered by a column on Oracle Server?

Tags: database, oracle, common-table-expression, rownum

In table `TEST`, I want to add a column `ID` and fill IDs in it incremented by 1 for each row. I need the IDs sorted with respect to column `COL`. So far, I have done this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD ID INTEGER;
UPDATE TEST SET ID = ROWNUM;
```

The problem in this method is IDs are not sorted with respect to `COL`. I need something like this:

`UPDATE TEST SET ID = (SELECT ROWNUM FROM TEST ORDER BY COL);`

but get an error. I have also tried CTE like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY COL
) UPDATE CTE SET ROWNUM = ID;
```

Getting the error `missing SELECT keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update test
  set id = (
    with cte as (
      select row_number() over (order by col) id, rowid rid from test
    )
    select id from cte where test.rowid = cte.rid
  );
```

Comment: This assumes `col` values are unique. If the OP is trying to assign ID's, for example, in increasing order by hire date (`col` is the hiring date), then this solution will error out when two or more employees were hired on the same date.

Comment: @mathguy here I fixed it ;)

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted as **not useful**. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29727148)

Answer (score 0):

Usually such tasks are more easily solved with a `merge` statement. For example:

```
merge into test t
using (select rowid as rid, row_number() over (order by col) as rn from test) s
   on (s.rid = t.rowid)
when matched then update set id = rn;
```